# error handling failed in laravel excel and queue

Tags: php, excel, laravel-8

I have tried to import csv using laravel excel and queue.I have tested import working without implement queue.its working perfectly.I was validate all rows before uploading csv.If validation error a mail will send to admin.Everything working fine without using queue.When i was using queue if no validation error it working.But if import function return validation error, error handling not working.it not hit the catch section.i checked the failed job.In exception column getting "maatwebsite\Excel\Validators\ValidationException: The given data was invalid. in C:\xampp\htdocs\user_import\vendor\maatwebsite\excel\src\Validators\RowValidator.php:68......".I dont know why error handling is not working in queue running.

controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use App\Imports\ImportUser;
use App\Http\Requests\UserImportRequest;
use  App\Events\ImportFailEvent;
class UserImportController extends Controller
{
    public function import(UserImportRequest $request)
    {
        try{
            Excel::import(new ImportUser, $request->file('file'));
        } catch (\Maatwebsite\Excel\Validators\ValidationException $e) {
            $failures = $e->failures();
            $failer_array = [];
            foreach ($failures as $failure) {
                $failer_array[] = $failure->errors()[0].$failure->row();
            }
            //send mail
            event(new ImportFailEvent($failer_array));
        }
    }
}
```

import user

```
namespace App\Imports;

use App\Models\ImportedUser;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithBatchInserts;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithChunkReading;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithValidation;
class ImportUser implements ToCollection,WithValidation,WithHeadingRow,WithBatchInserts, WithChunkReading, ShouldQueue
{
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'user_code' => 'required|regex:/^[a-bA-B0-9 ]+$/',
            'user_name' => 'required',
            'user_address' => 'required',
        ];
    }

    public function customValidationMessages()
    {
        return [
            'user_code.required'    => 'User Code is missing at row ',
            'user_code.regex'    => 'User Code contains symbols at row ',
            'user_name.required'       => 'User Name is missing at row ',
            'user_address.required'       => 'User Address is missing at row ',
        ];
    }
    
    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        foreach ($rows as $row) 
        {
            ImportedUser::create([
                'user_code' => $row['user_code'],
                'user_name' => $row['user_name'],
                'user_address' => $row['user_address'],
            ]);
        }
    }

    public function batchSize(): int
    {
        return 500;
    }

    public function chunkSize(): int
    {
        return 500;
    }

}
```

Comment: It's not getting that far. The request will hit the validator before it hits the function itself, because you're injecting the request/rules with `import(UserImportRequest $request)` -- see https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#creating-form-requests